# Determining the maximum possible size an image can be within a rectangle

Tags: javascript, algorithm, image, math

I have a function I'm using to determine the absolute maximum size an image can be (while retaining its aspect ratio) within a particular rectangle. The code I'm currently using is definitely wrong but I'm not sure where I went wrong.

```
// Sets the image to the largest proportional size possible
// based on the current browser window dimensions and original
// image size specified by the image loader
function applyLargestProportionalSize() {
    var maxWidth = <width of container>;
    var maxHeight = <height of container>;

    var realWidth = <actual image width>;
    var realHeight = <actual image height>;

    if (realWidth < realHeight && maxWidth > maxHeight) {
        var scaledWidth = Math.min(realWidth, maxWidth);
        $('img').css('width', scaledWidth);
        // let height be determined by the browser
    } else {
        var scaledHeight = Math.min(realHeight, maxHeight);
        $('img').css('height', scaledHeight);
        // let width be determined by the browser
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know the code is wrong?  What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know javascript, but the problem is that your code can handle only the cases in which the aspect ratio of the container is less than one, and the aspect ratio of the image is greater than one (or maybe I have that backwards, I'm not sure of the exact definition of aspect ratio). Try this:

```
if (realWidth/realHeight > maxWidth/maxHeight) {
  // everything else the same
```

Answer (score 0):

Scale the image dimensions for two cases:

1. To match the container's height, in which case you get a width

   ```
   scaled_width  = image_width  * container_height / image_height
   scaled_height = container_height
   ```
2. To match the container's width, in which case you get a height

   ```
   scaled_height  = image_height  * container_width / image_width
   scaled_width   = container_width
   ```

Then pick the first one where the computed dimension fits within the container.

If the image and the container are the same aspect ratio, they will both fit.

If the image is narrower-aspect than the container, only the first one will fit.

If the image is wider-aspect than the container, only the second one will fit.

Comment: For at least this part, "If the image and the container are the same aspect ratio, they will both fit.", wouldn't there be some issues with floating point comparisons using this method?

Comment: As it happens, the algorithm will work fine in integer arithmetic --- I deliberately put the multiply first for this reason. But even if you do it in float, it doesn't matter because we don't care if they're different by epsilon. The fact that they both fit is more a comment on what the algorithm is doing than a necessity for proper operation.